# Why transaction gas used increased after London hardfork?

Tags: solidity, gas, london

I am developing a smart contract and I recently updated Hardhat to 2.6.x, which has london hardfork as default network settings. My issue is that gas used by my transaction increased by more than 50% in most cases. When I switch back to berlin hardfork, the cost is "correct" again.

Can somebody explain me why? Is there some updated opcode gas cost list? Or did gas cost for storing / loading values from storage increased? I am failing in finding the source of the increase.

I read EIP-1559, but there is no much information about opcode updates, just gas price and model of a base fee burning, which should not increase transaction gas usage imo.

I use ethers and property `gasUsed` on transaction receipt to get used gas.

Comment: Can you provide transaction hashes that show the difference? The only EIP activated in London about gas is refund reductions EIP-3529 [London HF overview](https://medium.com/ethereum-cat-herders/london-upgrade-overview-8eccb0041b41). GasUsed should be similar than before unless you were using something similar to GasToken. GasPrices are changing a lot due to EIP-1559.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like EIP-3529 really is the reason. I am not implementing gas token and still it increases gas usage by 40k on previously 64k transaction. I work with ERC721 mostly and it looks like EIP-3529 made all transfers more expensive by ~20k gas because while transferring NFT you set storage of previous owner and (in some cases) his balance to 0, which are not refunded anymore. Unfortunate. I guess, there is nothing I can do to get to pre-EIP-3529 gas usage?